# mybatis-generator maven dependency issue

Tags: maven

I create a Maven project with the dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mybatis.generator</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis-generator-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

but it doesn't work. The error is:

> Missing artifact org.mybatis.generator:mybatis-generator-core:jar:1.3.3-SNAPSHOT

Comment: Do you explicitely want to use a SNAPSHOT version? Or the latest release version?

Comment: If you don't need something specific in version 1.3.3-SNAPSHOT use 1.3.2 instead. It seems 1.3.3-SNAPSHOT is not in global maven repository, only if you didn't configure to add other repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use version 1.3.3-SNAPSHOT of that dependency, you will need to add another repository. SNAPSHOT dependencies are generally not available on Maven Central and this one is not. It is available however in the [Sonatype Snapshot repository](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/mybatis/generator/mybatis-generator-core/1.3.3-SNAPSHOT/).

Thus, you need to [add the following repository](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html) to your POM or to your Maven settings:

```xml
<repository>
  <id>snapshots-repo</id>
  <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
  <releases>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
  </releases>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
  </snapshots>
</repository>
```

---

If you don't want to add that repository, then you will need to use the latest release version, which is [1.3.2](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mybatis.generator/mybatis-generator-core/1.3.2), and this one is available on Maven Central:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mybatis.generator</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis-generator-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you very much,understand now.